# Items in a row overflowing

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have 20 items in a list. I wish to display these items in a row only 3 or 4 items(depending on the length of the item) per row.

This is my code. The output I am getting is:

[image: my output screen]

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var width = screenSize.width;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 50,
        width: width,
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: List.generate(selectedStudentsIT.length, (index) {
            return Wrap(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 100,
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    semanticContainer: true,
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    elevation: 5,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "myowntext",// item from the list using the index
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have tried with WRAP widget, Flex and expanded also. But it does not solved my issue.

Comment: You need a ListView instead of a Row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your Row with SingleChlidScrollView.

```
SingleChildScrollView(scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal,child:Row(children......
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved my issue. However i need to display only 3 items per row. Any hint?

Comment: If thats the case, then you will need GridView.